# AutoMapper mapping from multiple properties to complex objects fails with ReverseMap and custom value resolver

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapper-10

I have issues on reverse mapping multiple properties back to complex objects, even with custom value resolvers.

Here are the persistence model:

```cs
public class EmailDbo
{
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSent { get; set; }
    public string SendTo { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool DownloadAvailable { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AdminDateSent { get; set; }
    public string AdminEmail { get; set; }
    public string AdminSubject { get; set; }
    public string AdminBody { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

I have Dapper map data from database and fill in this model.

Here are the domain models I want to map back and forth with the persistence model:

```cs
public class Email
{
    public string SendTo { get; private set; }
    public string Subject { get; private set; }
    public string Body { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? DateSent { get; private set; }
    
    public Email(string sendTo, string subject, string body, DateTime? dateSent = null)
    {
        // Validations
        this.SendTo = sendTo;
        this.Subject = subject;
        this.Body = body;
        this.DateSent = dateSent;
    }
}

public enum EmailTaskStatus
{
    Sent = 1,
    Unsent = 2
}

public class EmailTask
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }
    public Email PayerEmail { get; private set; }
    public Email AdminEmail { get; private set; }
    public bool DownloadAvailableForAdmin { get; private set; }
    public EmailTaskStatus Status { get; private set; }
    
    public EmailTask(int emailTaskId, DateTime dateCreated, Email payerEmail, Email adminEmail,
        bool downloadAvailable, EmailTaskStatus status)
    {
        // Validations
        this.Id = emailTaskId;
        this.DateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.PayerEmail = payerEmail;
        this.AdminEmail = adminEmail;
        this.DownloadAvailableForAdmin = downloadAvailable;
        this.Status = status;
    }
}
```

I would like to use a value object called `Email` for both the payer and admin email. You can tell they're just stored flatten in the database/persistence model. And the payer email is required but not the admin email.

I have the mapping configured like following:

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<EmailTask, EmailDbo>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SendTo, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PayerEmail.SendTo))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Subject, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PayerEmail.Subject))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Body, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PayerEmail.Body))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DateSent, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PayerEmail.DateSent))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DownloadAvailable, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DownloadAvailableForAdmin))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AdminEmail, opts => 
            {
                opts.PreCondition(src => (src.AdminEmail != null));
                opts.MapFrom(src => src.AdminEmail.SendTo);
            })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AdminSubject, opts =>
            {
                opts.PreCondition(src => (src.AdminEmail != null));
                opts.MapFrom(src => src.AdminEmail.Subject);
            })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AdminBody, opts =>
            {
                opts.PreCondition(src => (src.AdminEmail != null));
                opts.MapFrom(src => src.AdminEmail.Body);   
            })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AdminDateSent, opts =>
            {
                opts.PreCondition(src => (src.AdminEmail != null)); 
                opts.MapFrom(src => src.AdminEmail.DateSent);   
            })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StatusId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (int)src.Status))
            .ReverseMap()
                .ForCtorParam("status", opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.StatusId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PayerEmail, opts => opts.MapFrom<PayerEmailValueResolver>())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AdminEmail, opts => opts.MapFrom<AdminEmailValueResolver>());
    }
}
```

After `ReverseMap()`, I want to grab multiple properties and construct the complex object `Email`. Hence I define two [custom value resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) for that:

```cs
public class PayerEmailValueResolver : IValueResolver<EmailDbo, EmailTask, Email>
{
    public Email Resolve(EmailDbo emailDbo, EmailTask emailTask, Email email, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new Email(emailDbo.SendTo, emailDbo.Subject, emailDbo.Body, emailDbo.DateSent);  
    }
}

public class AdminEmailValueResolver : IValueResolver<EmailDbo, EmailTask, Email>
{
    public Email Resolve(EmailDbo emailDbo, EmailTask emailTask, Email email, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailDbo.AdminEmail) &&
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailDbo.AdminSubject) &&
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailDbo.AdminBody) &&
            !emailDbo.AdminDateSent.HasValue)
        {
            return null;
        }
        
        return new Email(emailDbo.SendTo, emailDbo.Subject, emailDbo.Body, emailDbo.DateSent);  
    }
}
```

As always, the mapping from the domain model to the Dbo works fine:

[image]

but not the other way, from Dbo to domain model. It's throwing exceptions:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Program+EmailTask needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. (Parameter 'type')
> at lambda_method32(Closure , Object , EmailTask , ResolutionContext )
> at AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMemberMap memberMap)
> at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination)
> at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)

**.Net Fiddle demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/DcTsPG

I wonder if AutoMapper confuses about those two `Email` objects: payer email and admin email, because they're both are `Email` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reverse map `AutoMapper` is failing to create an instance of `EmailTask`.

Add a parameterless constructor to your `EmailTask` class -

```
public EmailTask()
{
    // AutoMapper use only
}
```

Also, since your value resolvers are creating instance of `Email`, add a parameterless constructor to your `Email` class too -

```
public Email()
{
    // AutoMapper use only
}
```

Finally, modify the `PayerEmail` and `AdminEmail` properties in `EmailTask` class so they can be set publicly -

```
public Email PayerEmail { get; set; }
public Email AdminEmail { get; set; }
```

That should solve your issue.

**EDIT :**
@David Liang, after reading your comment I'd say, to suit your scenario in light of DDD, you might need to modify your current mapping approach.

The thing is, when you are mapping `EmailDbo` from `EmailTask`, the process is easier because `EmailDbo` is a DTO type class with no parameterized constructor. Therefore, the property mapping only is enough to do the job.

But when you are trying to map `EmailTask` from `EmailDbo`, you are trying to instantiate a domain model class which has very strictly defined parameterized constructor that takes complex types as parameters, and is trying to protect how it's properties can and cannot be accessed from outside. Therefore, the `.ReverseMap()` approach you are using currently will not be very helpful, because the property mapping only will not be enough to provide you all the constructor parameters needed to instantiate the class. There's also AutoMapper's naming convention in the play.

Following is a mapping configuration for `EmailTask` from `EmailDbo`, where the reverse mapping is separated out and the value resolvers are refactored out into a helper class. The forward mapping remained unchanged.

```
CreateMap<EmailDbo, EmailTask>()
    .ConstructUsing((s, d) =>
        new EmailTask(
                s.EmailId,
                s.DateCreated,
                Helper.GetPayerEmail(s),
                Helper.GetAdminEmail(s),
                s.DownloadAvailable,
                (EmailTaskStatus)s.StatusId))
    .IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter();
```

The `Helper` class -

```
public class Helper
{
    public static Email GetPayerEmail(EmailDbo emailDbo)
    {
        return new Email(emailDbo.SendTo, emailDbo.Subject, emailDbo.Body, emailDbo.DateSent);
    }

    public static Email GetAdminEmail(EmailDbo emailDbo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailDbo.AdminEmail) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailDbo.AdminSubject)
            && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailDbo.AdminBody) && !emailDbo.AdminDateSent.HasValue)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new Email(emailDbo.SendTo, emailDbo.Subject, emailDbo.Body, emailDbo.DateSent);
    }
}
```

Here is the complete fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/2MxSdt

Comment: Nope, that's not it. See my updated .net fiddle. I renamed `emailTaskId` to `emailId` and it's still failing.

Comment: @DavidLiang Updated the answer. Check if it works for you.

Comment: I know if I add a parameterless constructor it will work, but that will make the domain models in an invalid state. I don't want to do that. That's the whole point of having 2 sets of models: have Dapper map data to persistence models with public getters and setters, and have AutoMapper map persistence models to domain models, where I encapsulate the data and business logic. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @DavidLiang I myself too do not like parameterless ctors, neither in my domain models nor anywhere else. But I also tend not to pass complex types through my ctor, and make them publicly settable properties. I think your mapping is doable without parameterless ctors if you can make `PayerEmail` and `AdminEmail` to be publicly settable properties, and not ctor parameters.

Comment: I am practicing DDD and I wish every value object or entity I make would take only primitive types and fewer than 4 parameters through constructor, but that's usually not the reality here. Defining complex types with their own constructors works so well because you can define validations on them and other objects who reference them only need to check for NULL-lity. DDD favors value objects. Also making their properties publicly settable is not acceptable. If I had to make it to work, I would rather just manually map them rather than using AutoMapper.

Comment: @DavidLiang Please check the added Edit section.

Comment: Thanks @atiyar. Your updated solution works but it's basically just manual mapping. I want to try the hardest to see if AutoMapper can help, even just a little bit, on mapping from the Dto to the domain model. If I end up having to do the manual mapping, I will mark this as answer.

Comment: @DavidLiang Sure. But I'd really appreciate if you could do the trouble to notify my with a comment, and may be share your solution in a fiddle.

Comment: I've been trying for a day: tried creating couple custom value resolvers; tried putting private parameterless constructors in the complex objects. My unit tests are still throwing exceptions. I guess I will have to use manual mapping for unflattening data to complex objects then.

Comment: @DavidLiang In my experience, the idea of `auto` in `AutoMapper` works best for mapping from domain models to DTOs. But mapping from DTOs to domain models usually introduce friction when the model doesn't have parameterless constructor with fully public auto-properties, or have parameterized constructor, but the constructor parameter names doesn't match the property names.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping AutoMapper would do the trick. I've spent lots of time looking into other options like Mapster and ValueInjecter. I still like the documentation of AutoMapper. That's why I stick with it. My project uses Dapper to map data from database into DTOs. But that's kind of the same thing as AutoMapper: they have to have public setters.